# If part of a polynomial has complex roots then is it necessary that this polynomial must have complex roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let's say $P(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $k$ then $P'(x)$ is a polynomial with  degree $k-1$. What can be said about the roots of this polynomial?
$$f(x)=P(x)+(x^3 + x)P'(x)
$$
Since $(x^3 + x)$ has complex roots, is it necessary that $f(x)$ will have complex roots? If yes then why? And what can be said about the roots?

P.S coefficients of P and P' are real and P' may may or may not be derivative of P

Comment: So $P'$ is just any polynomial of degree one less, or is it in fact the derivative of $P$?

Comment: This is not clear.  All polynomials with complex coefficients have complex roots.

Comment: @lulu It is save to assume that in this context the OP means non-real

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick reference on MathJax which is used to type mathematics on this site. For your question, putting `$...$` around your expressions will for example turn `$x^3$` into $x^{3}$.

Comment: Not sure whether this matters, but if would be nice to know whether $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$ have real coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $k\ge3$. Let $$f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k-1)$$
(or any degree $k+2$ polynomial with all roots real).
Use polynomial division by $x^3+x$ to arrive at $f(x)-x^k=(x^3+x)P'(x)+R(x)$ and let $P(x)=x^k+R(x)$- Then $\deg P'=k-1$ and $\deg P=k$ as desired and $P(x)+(x^3+3)P'(x)$ has all roots real.